# Jquery select 2 placeholder not displayed

Tags: php, jquery

this is my code

```
<select class="m-b-10 form-control" name="sector[]"
                id="sector" multiple="multiple"
                data-placeholder="Select Sector(s)"
                data-toggle="select2" 
                data-validation="required"
                data-validation-error-msg="Select sectors">
    <option val="">select option</option>
    <option val="1">select option 1</option>
    <option val="2">select option 2</option>
    <option val="3">select option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript add this:

```
$("#sector").select2({
    placeholder: 'text',    
    width: "100%",
    maximumSelectionLength: 1,
    closeOnSelect: true
});
```